# How to add GUI to custom OpenAI gym enviroment?

Tags: python, graphics, pygame, game-development, openai-gym

I was following

1. [Beginners Guide To Custom Environments in OpenAIs Gym](https://towardsdatascience.com/beginners-guide-to-custom-environments-in-openai-s-gym-989371673952)
2. [O’Reilly’s Hands-on Intelligent Agents](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/hands-on-intelligent-agents/9781788836579/)

To set up an altogether new game for myself (sort of low graphic subway surfer). Though, I am able to understand how the mechanism are incorporated in a custom openai gym environment, I am still not able to make out how to add graphics to my game.Do I need a new library altogether & club it up with openai gym environment (like pygame)? New to game development hence need help.

Answer (score 0):

You will need separate files for the environment and the GUI, yes. The question is: why do you need the environment in the first place? If it is only for training your agent, then you can just import the trained agent into your GUI script and load it and then use it to make predictions and moves etc.